# Considering the output of the analysis variance for calculating other function

Tags: r

I have analysed my data using the ANOVA method and I got the below table:

```
Analysis of Variance Table:
---------------------------

      DF    SS       MS  F value      Pr(>F)    
t      2  48.2 24.10000  12.12500 0.000118890 ***
t:p   27 175.8  6.51111   9.73548 0.000267997 ***
t:r    9  79.7  8.85556  19.72044 0.000602435 ***
error 81 192.8  2.38025
```

Now I'd like to use this table and calculate the following functions:

```
X= (SS for t + SS for error)/(DF for error) = (48.2+192.8)/81
Y= (MS for t:p + MS for error)/(DF for error) = (6.51111+2.38025)/81
```

This give me these figures

```
X=2.975309
Y=0.10977
```

Is it possible to do it? Thanks for your help

Comment: you should show the data you ran the ANOVA on. I hope you did that in R. you.

Comment: can you also specify the libraries you have used and what you did to find that solution, please?
The function Anova from library car outputs something that you can directly use as a dataframe. That should help you get what you want.

Comment: I have used VCA in R. But it does not matter. The main point is only how we could extract some figures from the output of R to calculate other functions. If you generate some random data, that would be great. Thanks for your help.